# MAUI + DDD + EF Core Layered app. Issues with accessing to Repository service from xaml code behind

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, maui

I'm new in subject tech, thus plese forgive my dummy question ahead, as I understand that this shouldn't be a problem except my personal understanding issues :) Anyways, the issue which blowing my mind for almost a week is that I compleetly do not understand how to correctly call dbcontext from the xaml code behind, for instance when I click button, I want to pull some data from the databases.

The solution is pretty simple and i beleive standard, it consist of 4 projects:

1. MAUI Project
2. Domain Project
3. Infrastrucure project.

In MAUI project program.cs  i succesfully registring my infra

```
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure();
```

which goes to

```
public static class ServiceRegistration
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string dbPath = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath("my_db.db3");
            services.AddSingleton<IModelConfiguration, SQLiteModelConfiguration>();

            // Configuring the DBContext for to use specific data provider
            services.AddDbContext<MyMauiAppContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite(dbPath, sqliteOptions =>
                {
                    
                    sqliteOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ServiceRegistration).Assembly.FullName);
                });
            });

            services.AddDomain();
            return services;
        }
```

which is

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddDomain(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<CategoryService>();
        return services;
    }
```

which is

```
public class CategoryService
    {
        private MyMauiAppContext context;

        public CategoryService(MyMauiAppContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;

            if (context == null)
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        }

    }
```

So I'm lost here, I want to create a database once I click a button on MAUI app. In theory I should call a Category constructor, which is according to my understanind alrady has been instansiated and kept somwhere, but I compleetly do not understand how to correctly call it by using a builder work around done in Program.cs.

I appreaciate your time and help in advance,
Best regards,
Maks.

I would like to undertsand how to properly work with EF Core DBContext paradighm in MAUI stack

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection